# Extended partition should have many filesystems

Tags: partition, ext4, ntfs

I need some related information on the following lines I found in an answer:

> A logical partition is a container for a filesystem (or an LVM volume or some swap space or a BSD partition or other kind of volume that isn't a PC-style partition).

I want to create one extended partition in which I will keep all Xubuntu related boot var root home... as EXT4 filesystem logical partitions.
I also want that the extended partition should contain other logical NTFS volumes for my Windows/Linux accessible data (songs, movies, pdf, etc.)

Is a mix up like this possible with no problems?

Comment: Short answer is yes, it's possible. Are you having a specific issue setting that up? (Note that answers to questions on this site must be posted on this site, for the benefit of future visitors/people who have the same issue/question. Disclosing private email addresses is not something we do here.)

Comment: @Mat 
No I haven't set it up yet, about 415 GB unallocated space left. My  main issue is I want to keep all data as NTFS, and only OS specific data as their respective filesystems. How do I set up the home root boot var partitions in respect of space in GB? Any hints helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. There doesn't have to be any relation between the logical partitions inside an extended partition. The distinction between logical and primary partitions is just a gross hack because the original partition format only allowed 4 partitions.

In your setup, you'll presumably want four partitions, not counting the extended partition:

- a Windows system partition (containing an NTFS filesystem), which must be primary;
- a Linux system partition (containing an ext4 filesystem);
- a Linux swap partition;
- a data partition (as NTFS — the only serious option for sharing between Windows and Linux, but I would recommend ext4 for reliability, and instead copy those few files that you need under Windows back and forth).

Comment: Currently I got 2 partitions, a 100 MB for Windows system reserved, and a 50 GB to put all my Windows software in. Rest is unallocated. I want to install Linux into logical partitions and run them from there (I plan to install multiple distros).

Comment: @spawndon Ok, then that's 5 partitions total. You can have one extended partition containing the two Linux partitions and the data partition. If you intend a more complex setup with multiple Linux distributions, I recommend using LVM, it's a lot more flexible. Mind, nowadays, with virtualization, there's not much use for multiple OSes on the same machine.